# Xamarin forms List in List (navigating using prism)

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

The issue is that i cant seem to pass through the NavigationService to ModulesModel to use to Navigate to AnotherView items that i can only pass it to SectionModel. but i can only pass the NavigationService to the Parent ListView(Which i dont want) it needs to pass through the child ListView. HELP!!!

UI - CODE

```
      <ListView
      SeparatorColor="Transparent"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
      HasUnevenRows="True">
      <ListView.Header>
        <local:ModuleCourseHeaderViewControl />
      </ListView.Header>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Frame
              HasShadow="False"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BiancaBackgroundColour}">
              <Frame.CornerRadius>
                <OnIdiom
                  x:TypeArguments="x:Single"
                  Phone="0"
                  Tablet="15" />
              </Frame.CornerRadius>
              <Frame.Margin>
                <OnIdiom
                  x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Phone="0,10"
                  Tablet="20,10" />
              </Frame.Margin>
              <StackLayout>
                <Label
                  FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegularFont}"
                  TextColor="{StaticResource MediumGold}"
                  Text="{Binding Title}">
                  <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom
                      x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                      Phone="15"
                      Tablet="17" />
                  </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>

                <flv:FlowListView
                  BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  HasUnevenRows="False"
                  FlowColumnCount="{DynamicResource ModuleFlowColumnCount}"
                  RowHeight="{DynamicResource RiseCardHeight}"
                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
                  <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    <OnIdiom
                      x:TypeArguments="DataTemplate">
                      <OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <local:ModuleCourseCardPhoneControl>
                            <local:ModuleCourseCardPhoneControl.GestureRecognizers>
                              <TapGestureRecognizer
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" />
                            </local:ModuleCourseCardPhoneControl.GestureRecognizers>
                          </local:ModuleCourseCardPhoneControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                      </OnIdiom.Phone>
                      <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <local:ModuleCourseCardControl>
                            <local:ModuleCourseCardControl.GestureRecognizers>
                              <TapGestureRecognizer
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" />
                            </local:ModuleCourseCardControl.GestureRecognizers>
                          </local:ModuleCourseCardControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                      </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    </OnIdiom>
                  </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView>
              </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Models - CODE

```
public class NewModuleModel
{
    public IList<SectionModel> Sections { get; set; }
    public int ActiviyId { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
}

public class SectionModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<ModulesModel> Modules { get; set; }
    public INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }
}

public class ModulesModel
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ModuleImageUrl { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }
    public double RoundedProgress
    {
        get
        {
            var p = Math.Round(Progress * 100, 0);
            return p;
        }
    }
    public DateTime? LastActivityDTUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
    public string EstimatedDuration { get; set; }
    public int AssetCount { get; set; }
    public int? NavigationAssetID { get; set; }
    public int ActiviyId { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
    public int? NavigationAssetContentType { get; set; }
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            if (CompletedDate != null)
            {
                var c = String.Format("{0:d MMMM yyyy}", CompletedDate);
                result = "Completed on " + c;
            }
            else if (LastActivityDTUtc != null)
            {
                var l = String.Format("{0:d MMMM yyyy}", LastActivityDTUtc);
                result = "Last Activity on " + l;
            }
            else
            {
                result = "New";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }


    public ModulesModel()
    {
        
        ItemSelectedCommand = new DelegateCommand<ModulesModel>(this.OnCardItemSelectedCommand);
    }


    private void OnCardItemSelectedCommand(ModulesModel module)
    {
        if (module.NavigationAssetContentType == 28 && module.AssetCount == 1)
        {
            var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
            navigationParams.Add("AssetContentId", module.NavigationAssetID);
            navigationParams.Add("AssetActivityId", module.ActiviyId);
            navigationParams.Add("AssetModuleId", module.ModuleId);
            navigationParams.Add("ParamCourseTitle", module.CourseTitle);
            navigationParams.Add("ParamModuleTitle", module.Title);

            Preferences.Set("NavFromModulePage", true);

            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("AssetWebViewPage", navigationParams, true, false).Forget();

        }
        else
        {
            var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
            navigationParams.Add("ParamModuleId", module.ModuleId);
            navigationParams.Add("ParamActivityId", module.ActiviyId);
            navigationParams.Add("ParamCourseTitle", module.CourseTitle);

            Preferences.Set("NavFromModulePage", false);

            //NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ModuleAssetPage", navigationParams, true, false);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand<ModulesModel> ItemSelectedCommand { get; set; }
}
```

}

ViewModel - CODE

```
    private async void LoadData()
    {           
            this.ExecuteAsyncTask(async () =>
            {
                var result = await this.ModuleService.GetNewModuleAsync(ActivityID);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    CourseTitle = result.CourseTitle;
                    CourseDescription = result.CourseDescription;
                    CourseImageUrl = result.CourseImageUrl;
                    DurationInSeconds = result.DurationInSeconds;
                    DurationAsReadableString = result.DurationAsReadableString;
                    DisplayDescription = result.DisplayDescription;
                    Progress = Math.Round(result.Progress * 100, 0);
                    StartDateUTC = result.StartDateUTC;
                    EnrolmentDate = result.EnrolmentDate;
                    LastActivityDate = result.LastActivityDate;

                    foreach (var item in result.Sections)
                    {
                        var itemToAdd = new SectionModel
                        {
                            Title = item.Title,                  
                            Modules = item.Modules,
                            NavigationService = navigationService
                        };
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            this.Data.Add(itemToAdd);
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var exception = new Exception($"Api Error");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that MVVM is Model-View-ViewModel. Very often we see people confusing Models and ViewModel's. I'll more indirectly answer your question by showing you the proper architecture. To start we'll look at a `ToDoItem` model.

```cs
public class ToDoItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Due { get; set; }
}
```

With this note that we can make this easier to Bind by having our model inherit from something like Prism's `BindableBase` or ReactiveUI's `ReactiveObject`. I will make the assumption here that you already understand how to make those properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

The next thing we need is our ViewModel, we'll say that this is the ToDoItemsPageViewModel

```cs
public class ToDoItemsPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> Items { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand<ToDoItem> ItemSelectedCommand { get; }

    private async void ItemSelectedCommandExecuted(ToDoItem item)
    {
        // do your navigation here..
    }
}
```

Finally we have our ListView or CollectionView (which is what you should use as ListView is being deprecated). For simplicity let's look at the following.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Button Text="Show"
                Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The core idea to understand here is that the ListView shares the BindingContext of its parent Page. Within our DataTemplate our BindingContext is a `ToDoItem` and not the `ToDoItemsPageViewModel`. As a result our binding for the value of `Name` will return the name of the individual ToDoItem. While our Binding for the CommandParameter will pass in the entire ToDoItem, our Binding for the Command will not work because the ToDoItem has no such command.

Now let's look at how we can access the Command from our ViewModel.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="list">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Button Text="Show"
                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand,Source={x:Reference list}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What we've done here are three small changes.

- We've added an `x:Name` to the ListView. This could also be put on the parent Page.
- We've changed the Command Binding from `ItemSelectedCommand` to `BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand`
- We've changed the Command Binding to include a `Source` which references the parent item (the list in this case)

What this accomplishes is to update that one specific binding to look at the parent. This effectively sets the BindingContext (for this single property) to the actual parent. In this case you can think of it as the BindingContext being set to the instance of the ListView. This means that our Binding must reference the BindingContext, and then we can dot into access a property of our BindingContext on the ListView.

Comment: yh that was my 1st approach but adding a command to the FlowList didn't work for me as the it never went to the delegateCommand that i created. this was the alternative approach that i found.